# (HTML & CSS) How to hide checkbox while still being able to check image

Tags: html, css, checkbox, google-chrome-extension

I've been creating a checkbox that has a custom background image.  I want to hide the checkbox, but whenever I do I am unable to check it.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="arrow">
  <label for="togglearrow"></label>
  <input type='checkbox' id="togglearrow"/>
  <div class="arrowmenu"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#togglearrow {
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.arrow {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  background: url('arrow.png') no-repeat;
  background-size: 65%;
  height: 35px;
  bottom: 0;
}

.arrowmenu {
  position: absolute;
  background: url('test.png') no-repeat;
  background-size: 65%;
  height: 35px;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 20px;
}

label[for="togglearrow"] {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#togglearrow:checked + .arrowmenu {
  display: block;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

I expect that the checkbox will be hidden and can still click on "tasks.png" to check the box, however, it results in the checkbox not being able to be checked.

Comment: Don't hide it, instead just set its `opacity` to 0, `position` to `absolute`, and move/stretch it to occupy the entire click area.

Answer (score 0):

Your `<label>` element doesn't have any dimensions.

Also, I am unsure which element `tasks.png` is referring to.

```css
#togglearrow {
  display: none;
}

.arrow {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  background: url('https://unsplash.it/100') no-repeat;
  background-size: 65%;
  height: 35px;
  bottom: 0;
}

.arrowmenu {
  position: absolute;
  background: url('https://unsplash.it/300') no-repeat;
  background-size: 65%;
  height: 35px;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 20px;
}

label[for="togglearrow"] {
      display: block;
      cursor: pointer;
      width: 40px;
      height: 100%;
      border: 1px solid yellow;
}

#togglearrow:checked + .arrowmenu {
      display: block;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 50px;
      -webkit-user-select: none;
      -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
      user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow">
  <label for="togglearrow"></label>
  <input type='checkbox' id="togglearrow"/>
  <div class="arrowmenu"></div>
</div>
```

---